# How to show complete output even though it's error?

Tags: php, command

I have following php script in which I am trying to execute a command on Windows and print it's output. I have tried *system()*, *shell_exec()*, *passthru()* and *exec()*.

```
$cmd = $_POST['cmd'];
$result = array();
exec($cmd, $result);
foreach ($result as $line ){
 echo $line."<br>";
}
```

*exec($command, $array)* is the closest to my expectation of printing everything when a command is executed. I wish to print everything even though it's an error. But it only prints when command is executed successfully.

How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` only contains the standard output of the command, but error messages are usually written to standard error. You need to redirect stderr to stdout when running the command.

```
$cmd = "$cmd 2>&1"
exec($cmd, $result);
```

[In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)

Comment: What's use of 2>&1 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean